How to Specify Managed Resource Path in Solr
How do I specify the default path to managed resources files in solr.
I am using synonyms via managed resources api and it creates the synonyms config file
under  /var/solr/data/collection1/conf/_schema_analysis_synonyms_english.json
I want to change the default path here to something else.
How do i do this?
I am using the managed api resource so i do not have a physical synonyms.txt file

I found out how to do this by peeking through the solr source code.
solrconfig.xml
    <restManager>
        <str name="storageDir">/var/solr/data/mycore/data/managed_resources</str>
    </restManager>

That did the trick.
